# Root under the root with summation or product

Tags: summation, roots

I have a question about an equation that I would like to obtain through either a product or a summation.

I would like to get a **root sequence under roots** that I can continue depending on n times:

$$\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4}}}$$

I would like to achieve the same result, but with a summation or a product.

And for days now I have been making attempts without obtaining concrete results
Thank you very much

Comment: What's a "producer"?  Do you mean "product"?  But your expression is a product already.

Comment: @lulu I mean this: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produttoria                                            Excuse me but the name changes a lot with the languages and I have no idea what it is called in English.

Comment: Yes, that's "product" in English.  But your expression is written as a product already.  Well, I suppose I would think of it recursively.  That is, we can get your expression as a recursive function on lists by $F(\{a_1,\cdots, a_n\})=\sqrt {a_1\times F(\{a_2,\cdots, a_n\})}$ and $F(\{a\})=\sqrt a$.  Not sure what more you are hoping for.

Comment: If you like, you can "unnest" the radicals.  Thus, for length $2$, we'd have $x=\sqrt {a_1\times \sqrt {a_2}}\implies x^4=a_1^2\times a_2\implies x=\left(a_1^2\times a_2\right)^{1/4}$ Is that the sort of thing you wanted?

Comment: the most it is to do a recursive function, Thank you for your valuable help

Comment: @lulu suppose I want to put your formula for the succession (first comment) in walfram alpha, can you give me the LaTex for the formula?

Comment: I'm not a big Mathematica programmer.  I think other people could write the recursion more efficiently than I could.

Comment: @lulu I applied your formula but I get wrong values, can you tell me what I did wrong? Result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(%7Bn%2B1%7D)%3D%5Csqrt%7B2*f(%7Bn%2B2%7D)%7D,+f(1)%3D%5Csqrt%7B2%7D

Comment: Like I say, I'm not the best guy to ask about Mathematica code.  I don't believe there's anything wrong with my formula...I think I have just written down exactly what you are doing.  For two variable it certainly works...but I'd ask someone else about the actual code.

Comment: okay, thank you for your help in the meantime! i got good results thanks to your advice! The value f {a1,⋯,an}  Does it match the N+1 formula for the first launch to be two?                                                          a1 equals 2 as a2 equals 3?

Comment: I get $f({2,3})=\sqrt {2\times f({3})}=\sqrt {2\times \sqrt 3}=1.861209718$.  Or, using the other expression I wrote, $f(2,3)=(2^2\times 3)^{1/4}=1.861209718$.